# How to get data from asObservable()

Tags: angular, observable, angular2-observables, query-string

this my service code, let the service name be setGetContext

```
_params: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();

getParameters(): Observable<SearchContext> {
    return this._params.asObservable();
}

setParameters(search: SearchContext) {
    this._params.next("Test");
}
```

In the other component i'm trying to get the value of params.

```
this.setGetContext.getParameters().subscribe((data) => {
    console.log(data);
})
```

Here I'm not getting data and the code is not even triggered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The service:

```
public _params: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();
setParameters(search: SearchContext) {
  this._params.next({action:'test'});
}
```

The component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { Your service } from 'service_route'

export class YourComponent implements OnInit {
    public subscription: Subscription;

    constructor(private _serv: YourService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
       this.handleSubscriptions();
    }
    public handleSubscriptions() {
      this.subscription = this._serv._params.subscribe(
        action => {
            console.log(action);
        }
      )
    }
}
```

Now you can call your service function and everytime you call it your component will console.log 'test'

Comment: Are you calling _serv.setParameters() after doing that?

Comment: The problem console statement is not triggered at all

Comment: But please could you answer my question? The console statement will only be triggered when you call to your setParameters() service function. This is the way I work usually, never had a problem with this. I use this subscription for several functionalities such as sidebars ( to open it and close it ) notification growls and so on. Confirm if you called to the function and if you did I will check the code for if i made a mistake. Thank you

Comment: Thanks its working... I really forgot to assign tge value

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

**Your Service:**

```
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import { distinctUntilChanged, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

private _paramSubject = new BehaviorSubject<any>({} as any);
public _params = this._paramSubject.asObservable().pipe(distinctUntilChanged());

setParameters(search: SearchContext) {
    this._paramSubject.next("Test");
}
```

**In the component:**

```
setParameters(<YOUR OBJECT>)
service._params.subscribe(data => {console.log(data)});
```

Comment: This is working, when it is **BehaviourSubject** and not working when it is **Subject**