# How can i change the attribute from other component in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two components:

Register and Login.

In the RegisterComponent i have the anchor:

```
<a id="titleClient">Already have a account? Click here</a>
```

I need when the user click in this anchor set the Login attribute already_client to true:

```
export class LoginComponentimplements OnInit {
  already_client: boolean
  ...
}
```

I try to input property but i use  to show this components, i can't use `<app-logincomponent [already-client]="true">` 
How can i do this?

Thanks

Comment: Using EventEmitters, Subjects and Observables. Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51380223/how-to-get-data-from-asobservable/51380370#51380370

Comment: I try:   public handleSubscriptions() {
    this.subscription = this.registrarService.setCliente_JControle.subscribe(
      action => {
          console.log(action);
      }
    )
  }

in service:   setCliente_JControle(possui_conta: boolean) {
    this.cliente_jcontrole.next({action: true});
  }


but i get: [ts] Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type '(possui_conta: boolean) => void'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me:

login:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.handleSubscriptions()
  }

  public handleSubscriptions() {
    this.subscription = this.registrarService.params.subscribe(
      action => {
        if(action !== undefined){
          this.usuario.client= action.action
        }
      }
    )
  }
```

Register

```
  setPossui(){
    this.registrarService.setParameters(true);
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
  }
```

Service:

```
private client: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>({} as any);
  public params = this.cliente.asObservable().pipe(distinctUntilChanged());

  public setParameters(possui_conta: boolean) {
    this.client.next({action: possui_conta});
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, Import the compenent to your Parent component that you want to change value from... Let's say child, import child to your parent component:

parentComponent.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";
import { myChildComponent } from "./myChildComponent";

//inject child component to use its own functions.
@ViewChild(myChildComponent) childComponent: myChildComponent;

changeChild(){
this.childComponent.setAuthorization(true);
}
```

After that you can use function inside your child component.

in myChildComponent.ts

```
//You will reach this function from your Parent component...
setAuthorization(state: boolean){
 this.myAuthState = state;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have using the login component in the Registration Component then it would be pretty simple by using @Input decorator.

#### ts

```
import Input from "@angular/core";

export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input("user-client")
  already_client: boolean
  ...
}
```

#### html

```
<a id="titleClient" (click)="alreadyClient = true">Already have a account? Click here</a>
<app-logincomponent [already-client]="alreadyClient ">
```